# Firestore query returns empty array when there is data that should be returned

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I have this problem where my query returns an empty array. I get no error messages and I see no typos in the query. This is a learning project, following Firehip's NextJS course, but the firebase syntax has been updated from the source code to v9. Apart from this change, I see no discrepancies from the course source code, so I believe the issue lies on Firebase side.

Code:

helperFunction.tsx:

```
export async function getUserWithUsername(username: string) {
    const q = query(
        collection(firestore, "users"),
        where("username", "==", username),
        limit(1)
    );
    const userDoc = (await getDocs(q)).docs[0];
    return userDoc;
}
```

index.tsx:

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ query: urlQuery }) {
    const { username } = urlQuery;

    const userDoc = await getUserWithUsername(username);

    let user: object = {};
    let posts: any[] = [];

    if (userDoc) {
        user = userDoc.data();

        const postsQuery = query(
            collection(getFirestore(), userDoc.ref.path, "posts"),
            where("published", "==", true),
            orderBy("createdAt", "desc"),
            limit(5)
        );

        posts = (await getDocs(postsQuery)).docs.map(postToJSON);
        console.log("posts in users page", posts);
    }

    return {
        props: { user, posts },
    };
}

    export default function UserProfilePage({ user, posts }) {
    return (
        <main>
            <h1>User's page</h1>
            <UserProfile user={user} />
            <PostFeed posts={posts} />
        </main>
    );
}
```

Terminal output:

```
posts in users page []
```

The same query made in firestore interface:
[image: firestore query screen]

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73876736/there-is-a-problem-i-am-facing-while-getting-data-from-firebase-i-am-getting-emp) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61842126/firebase-get-request-returning-empty-array)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I don't see any applicability to my case. Thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it eventually.
The problem was on the firestore side, as expected.

I had wrong data layout. I had a `posts` collection, in which the posts were created by hand.
However, the query in the file was for `userID/posts` collection, so it returned empty.

I learned something about firestore in the process, so there's that.